Was linguistic value addition given to Mtt 1:6 by the translations?
We read in just a few Versions of Mtt 1:6 for instance, ESV:

and Jesse the father of David the king.And David was the father of Solomon by the wife of Uriah

But, most of the Versions, eg KJV read :

And Jesse begat David the king; and David the king begat Solomon of her that had been the wife of Urias;

Now, after the death of Uriah, King David solemnised his marriage with Bathsheba, widow of the former . Though Bathsheba had conceived  David's child  before Uriah was killed in war, the child did not survive. Solomon would later be born to the couple. That said, it would not be technically right for the Evangelist to use the words ' of the wife of Uriah ' . Interestingly, many Versions use italics for the phrase ' she who had been the wife of ' .
One is therefore, inclined to conclude that the original  construction of Verse 6 somehow was not clear enough , and that the English translations used the Past Perfect Tense to describe the relation of Bathsheba to her deceased  husband Uriah, thereby giving  a linguistic value addition to Verse 6. What is the view of Bible scholars on such a  prospect ?
PS: A question on the topic was asked on BHE on 25 th Feb 2023. I am however, looking for some new perspectives. Please bear with me.

ek te tou Ourio indicates that Solomon was begotten 'out of' 'the (fem)' of 'that(masc)' of Uriah. The deceased Uriah is recognised  to have masculinely possessed something in his life that was feminine and still living. Out of that was begotten Solomon. This is a real lesson in the power of the Greek Article. Up-voted +1.

Here's the literal Greek of Matthew 1:6b from Biblehub.com.

Notice that the Greek word, tēs, is an article, Genitive Feminine Singular, that's followed by another article, tou, Genitive Masculine Singular. This references the former wife of Uriah, Bathsheba, without mentioning her name. Why do you think this was the case?
You can see the choices made in many other Bible translations here:
https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Matthew%201%3A6

+1. Good answer.

"Why do you think this was the case?" Answering a question with a question isn't the best approach.

Thank you, @Dottard.  And I'm trying to provide the OP with the opportunity to look at the two articles in a row, the first one feminine, the second masculine, to see what's hidden in the text. Discovery is often much more rewarding than being told. Besides the link I provided allows the reader to compare many English translations to see how different teams of translation experts handled this question.

Thanks, Dieter . I stand enlightened. But, when a question is accepted by BHE, it becomes the property of all its esteemed Users. To many like me, Greek is Greek !
